# Connect to AWS Neptune with Golang GremlinGo

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, graphql, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am at the moment trying to set up a connection to AWS Neptune via go, but its not working. I am able to connect to AWS itself, but when I try to connect to Neptune DB it says "no successful connections could be made: dial tcp 172.31.4.48:8182: i/o timeout". I am using the Gremlingo module like in this code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/neptune"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

    gremlingo "github.com/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin-go/v3/driver"
)

func main() {

    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region:      aws.String("us-east-id1"),
        Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentials("AWS-id key", "aws secret id key", ""),
    })

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Couldn't create new session")
        return
    }

    neptune.New(sess)

    driverRemoteConnection, err := gremlingo.NewDriverRemoteConnection("wss://database-1-instance-1.asdasdasd.us-east-1.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182/gremlin",
        func(settings *gremlingo.DriverRemoteConnectionSettings) {
            settings.TraversalSource = "g"
        })

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    //Cleanup
    defer driverRemoteConnection.Close()

    //Creating graph traversal
    g := gremlingo.Traversal_().WithRemote(driverRemoteConnection)

    // Perform traversal
    results, err := g.V().Limit(2).ToList()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // print results
    for _, r := range results {
        fmt.Println(r.GetString())
    }
}
```

I wasn't quite sure what the problem was so I tried to connect to the cluster itself and as it didn't work I tried to connect to the Writer.
Thank you very much for your help.

Best regards

Comment: Does the location you are running your code from have access to the VPC that Neptune is in?

Comment: thank you very much Kelvin, that was the problem I think.

Comment: OK thanks for letting me know, I'll write that up as an answer in case others have the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Neptune runs inside of a VPC and does not expose a public endpoint. Code designed to send queries must have access tho that VPC. This could be as simple as the code running on an EC2 instance in the same VPC, but there are many other ways that access to a VPC can be granted, such as Load Balancers, VPC Peering, Direct Connect, and many others.

An easy way to check if your code can access the database, is to send an HTTP request to the `/status` API from the same point of origin and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

i use another client lib like "grammes", its worked well, but "gremlingo" failed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnQF7.png)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34753239)

Comment: Please take care to correct your English as well as format the post correctly, including inserting images.